# Multi-line regular expressions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I cannot figure a way to make regular expression match stop not on end of line, but on end of file in VS Code? Is it a tool limitation or there is some kind of pattern that I am not aware of?

Comment: Doesn't `[\s\S]` work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, first of all it maches a single character, and with `*` quantifier it stops on EOL

Answer (score 163, accepted):

It seems the CR is not matched with `[\s\S]`. Add `\r` to this character class:

```
[\s\S\r]+
```

will match *any* 1+ chars.

Other alternatives that proved working are `[^\r]+` and `[\w\W]+`.

If you want to make any character class match line breaks, be it a positive or negative character class, you need to add `\r` in it.

**Examples**:

- Any text between the two closest `a` and `b` chars: `a[^ab\r]*b`
- Any text between `START` and the closest `STOP` words:

  - `START[\s\S\r]*?STOP`
  - `START[^\r]*?STOP`
  - `START[\w\W]*?STOP`
- Any text between the closest `START` and `STOP` words:

  - `START(?:(?!START)[\s\S\r])*?STOP`

See a demo screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks. Tried `\n`, forgot about `\r`

Comment: @AymericBouzyaybbyk Yes, I am trying to keep this answer up-to-date, you may check the [answer revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41151078/revisions). It did not work for some time, but the developers fixed the bug they introduced before.

Comment: how do I do a multiline negated character class?

Comment: @MichaelJohnston The linebreak is matched with `\r`/`\n`. Adding that to a negated character class can be done with the help of alternation, or pattern re-writing. In the generic form, it may look like `(?:\r|[^pattern])*`. I have just tested and `[^pattern\r]*` works, too, although this looks weird.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it does look weird, and there are some other weird things...I _think_ what's going on is if you use `\n` anywhere in the regex, `*` & `[^]` etc. start matching newlines.

Comment: When the file is very large, \r or \n doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 14):

To match a multi-line text block starting from `aaa` and ending with the first `bbb` (lazy qualifier)

```
aaa(.|\n)+?bbb
```

To find a multi-line text block starting from `aaa` and ending with the last `bbb`. (greedy qualifier)

```
aaa(.|\n)+bbb
```

Comment: This is helpful. Simple and easy.  pipe character saves the day.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude certain characters from the "in between" text, you can do that too. This only finds blocks where the character "c" doesn't occur between "aaa" and "bbb":

```
aaa([^c]|\n)+?bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my self trying to remove comments in HTML.

Based on @genevieve-warren's answer I came up with this regex which removes blocks (multiline) of HTML comments except conditional comments:

```
<!--[^[if](.|\n)+?-->
```