# VS Code multiline search and replace for HTML / XML tags?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How to search for a start and ending tag that may include multiple non-blank lines?

```
<body myattr="hello" >
  <title>Hello</title>
</body>

<element>Surprise!!!</element>

<body myattr="goodbye" >
  <title>Goodbye</title>
</body>
```

Answer (score 15):

Answer kindly provided to me by VS Code developer.  May it help others.

Thank you @roblourens!

```
<body[\n\s\S]*?</body>
```

This is useful to replace or delete unwanted elements in XML or HTML.