# Search and replace JSON multiline using regex in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a really long JSON schema. Using VSCode, I need to replace the `partnerName`  type to be `string, null` (it appears more than 20 times, the snippet below is just 1 appearance).

How can I search and replace the multiline for the entire `partnerName` entry?

From other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647894/multiline-regular-expression-search-in-visual-studio-code/52650281), I've tried using regex `[\n\s]+`, `(.*\n)+` to be
`"partnerName": {(.*\n)+"type": "null"(.*\n)+}`

But it's still not matching.

Search for:

```
"partnerName": {
          "type": "null"
        },
```

Replace with:

```
"partnerName": {
          "type": "string, null"
        },
```

Snippet example:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "node": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "frequency": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "maxCount": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "points": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "startAt": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "endAt": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "partnerName": {
          "type": "null"
        },
        "action": {
          "type": "null"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "description",
        "type",
        "frequency",
        "maxCount",
        "points",
        "startAt",
        "endAt",
        "partnerName",
        "action"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "node"
  ]
},
```

Comment: You really should be parsing the json and then setting the value you want, but if you must use regex try: `(partnerName".*\n\s*"type":\s*)"null"` .

Comment: @Mark not sure what do you mean by parsing but the regex works :) thanks a lot! I'd mark it as the correct answer if you added as an answer

Comment: Are you using javascript and nodejs?

Comment: i'm ios dev and using swift daily. but for this schema, i'm writing a rest api contract test using ruby (cucumber) .. so, it's just a search & replace using text editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(partnerName".*\n\s*"type":\s*)"null"
```

and replace with:

```
$1"string, null"
```

Comment: what's $1 referring to here? is it the second regex on `\s*` ?

Comment: `$1` is the first capture group `(partnerName"."\n\s*"type":\s*)

Comment: This works in this specific instance, but is there any way to get . (DOT) to match newlines?