# How to remove a whole line in VS code search and replace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The futurize automatically added some line into my codebase. Most of the time is on the first line.

from builtins import object

I would like to delete that line completely. So something like this

```
from builtins import object
import logging
```

will become

```
import logging
```

I have tried to use \b, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you mean with just the keyboard? I use the plugin IntelliJ Keyboard Bindings. Then I use command + delete on Mac, or Ctrl + Delete on Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how to do that in search and replace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiline regular expression search in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647894/multiline-regular-expression-search-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to remove completely a line in VS Code through "Search and replace" you need to enable the RegExp function, then you type the line you want to remove followed by a "\n" and you leave the Replace field empty.

[image]

Comment: I had to do `^[\s]*your text\n` to not mess up the whitespaces around the replaced text.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Mattia's answer:

Alternatively you can use `SHIFT + ENTER` (instead `\n`) without enabling the regexp.

[image]