# VSCode multiline search of two words?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647894/multiline-regular-expression-search-in-visual-studio-code) that says you can search using regex or an actual literal text on it to search multiline texts. But what if you want to (quickly) search two or three of words within a specified lines of text content?

For example, what if you want to search for multiline text area that contains "ruby" and "regex" (assuming you want to know where you took a note on your txt (or markdown or rich text format) file. you may want to search for "how to use regex in ruby" or "the ruby regex tutorial", right? )

Now you can use a simple (but redundant) regex like `ruby(.*\n)+regex|regex(.*\n)+ruby`. But to me it doesn't look beautiful. For three or more words, this kind of regex workaround increases its redundancy exponentially also, not good.

So is there a smarter way to do this? Thanks.