# Writing ECMAScript Javascript Regex to Vscode search?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I get the pattern.
`/(?<=<TOTA>[^]+\blength=")[^"]+(?="[^]+<\/TOTA>)/g`

And test on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) ,it can work in `ECMAScript` mode.

Now I want to use pattern in Vscode search,
how to convert the pattern??

Below is the examples of a file.

```
<TxDef encoding="EBCDIC" txAdapter="Unisys" appAdapter="pass" xmlTransformer="Unisys" transportAdapter="SystemF" targetTx="" txMapper="" delimiter="" memo="pp">
  <TITA>
      <TxBlock dataTag="" renderTag="Y" memo="" ref="SystemF-TITA-COM-AREA" />
      <TxField id="BCURCD" cname="cc" datatype="9" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="2" lengthExpr="" scale="0" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
      <TxField id="STATUS" cname="c6" datatype="9" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="1" lengthExpr="" scale="0" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
      <TxField id="END" cname="gg" datatype="X" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="1" lengthExpr="" scale="0" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
    </TxBody>
    <TxTail dataTag="" renderTag="Y" memo="" ref="" />
  </TITA>
  <TOTA>
    <TxHead dataTag="" renderTag="Y" memo="" ref="" />
    <TxBody dataTag="CommMsg" renderTag="Y" memo="" ref="">
      <TxRepeat dataTag="TXREC" renderTag="Y" memo="" timesField="" timesValue="-1" name="">
        <TxBlock dataTag="Header" renderTag="N" memo="" ref="SystemF-TOTA-BASIC-TxBlock" />
        <TxSwitch dataTag="" renderTag="N" memo="" switchField="WARN">
          <TxCase dataTag="" renderTag="N" memo="" value="[default]">
            <TxRepeat dataTag="TXREC" renderTag="N" memo="" timesField="" timesValue="1" name="">
              <TxField id="CNAME" cname="ed" datatype="X" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="80" lengthExpr="" scale="0" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="UNISYS" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
              <TxField id="AVBAL" cname="b7" datatype="S" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="14" lengthExpr="" scale="2" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
              <TxField id="AVG03" cname="hh" datatype="9" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="13" lengthExpr="" scale="2" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
              <TxField id="AVG1" cname="1m" datatype="9" lengthtype="F" padchar=" " justify="" default="" length="13" lengthExpr="" scale="2" tagSize="0" lengthSize="0" encoding="" shiftInOut="Y" invisibleChar="TrimAndPadRight" memo="" optional="N" overwrite="N" codec="" renderTag="" charFormat="" />
               </TxRepeat>
            </TxRepeat>
          </TxCase >
        </TxSwitch >
      </TxRepeat >
    </TxBody>
    <TxTail dataTag="" renderTag="Y" memo="" ref="" />
  </TOTA>
</TxDef>
```

Comment: Try: `(?<=<TOTA>[\s\S]+\blength=\")[^\"]+(?=\"[\s\S]+</TOTA>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that VS Code currently does not understand `[^]`. Note: regex101.com explains that `[^]` "*matches any character, including newline*". [This VS Code search SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000581/11107541) suggests using `(.|\n)`, which should be functionally equivalent.

```
(?<=<TOTA>(.|\n)+\blength=")[^"]+(?="(.|\n)+<\/TOTA>)
```

What happens next depends on whether you are searching withing a single file editor, or searching over multiple files. According to [this GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143453#issuecomment-1048139108),

> search in the editor uses the JS regex engine, and search across files uses [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which doesn't support [variable-length lookbehind assertions]. There are a small number of differences in regex feature support, this is one of them.

So it will work when searching in a single file editor, but when searching over multiple files, VS Code will error "*Regex parse error: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length*"

This limitation of ripgrep is inherent to its design, and would probably require a complete redesign violating its original goals to implement it. See these closed issues on the maintainer (BurntSushi)'s repo:

- [Regexp expression failure when using lookbehind](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/644)
- [allow handling lookbehind assertions of non-fixed length](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/1025)