# Why doesn't my regex work with VS Codes' search function?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have to find and replace a load of HTML which has a similar layout to this (I've left the formatting to demonstrate how it actually looks inline):

```html
   <div  
     class="text-dark font-weight-normal mb-0 mt-0 item-card2-desc">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-map-signs"></i> Get
          Directions</a>
  </div>
```

I need to find and replace Get Directions with another string, let's say "Hello World" in VS Code.  I've used RegExr to build this and validate it against the above but whilst it works on RegExr, VS Code finds no matches:

```
(Get)\s+(Directions)
```

Is there a VS Code format I've not applied?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647894/multiline-regular-expression-search-in-visual-studio-code "a regex search executes in multiline mode only if it contains a \n literal"

Comment: Dang, I "fixed" the code formatting but that was bad, as it was necessary to show your problem.  Sorry, please revert.  [On the plus side, the quote in  the above comment was from one of my answers...]

Comment: I re-edited, probably where it needs to be now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that VS Code will search within the line, and in your example, `Get` and `Directions` are in different lines.

I tried `(Get)[\s\n]+(Directions)` and it worked. Just be aware that if you replace this, you will replace the line break as well.

Comment: VSC does not search within a line, It searches in the whole document text. According to MDN `\s` includes `\n` so `[\s\n]` is the same as `\s`

Comment: As stated in a comment to the question, VS Code will not search the whole document unless `\n` is present within the expression. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647894/multiline-regular-expression-search-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: but that means that VSC build on Electron build on Node uses a regex search that is not compliant with the doc on MDN, or is MDN a variant of the EcmaScript standard

Comment: @rioV8 VSCode has always needed an explicit `\n` to search across newlines.  Or same with Ctrl+Enter in the find/search widget to enter a linebreak.