Regex works in regex101 but not in VSCode - How to fix?
I'm trying to use a regular expression in Visual Studio Code to match a pattern in my text. The text is as follows:
Cat
AAAAAAAAAAAAAa
Dog
Cat
BbbbbbbbbbBbb
Dog

I want to match everything from "Cat" up to, but not including, the next "Dog". I've tried using the following regex, which works perfectly in regex101:
/(Cat[\s\S]*?(?=Dog))/gm

Here is the regex101 link for reference.
However, when I copy this regex to VSCode, it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why there's a discrepancy between the two platforms. Could anyone explain why this is happening and how I can get the regex to work in VSCode?

Thank you in advance for your help!

It looks like you are not searching in multiline mode in VSCode. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53270908/1467914 (I would guess that at regex101 the m at the end of your search expression is just for that - multiline matching)

This is common problem in the vscode Find Widget.  You need to indicate explicitly that you want to include newlines in your query.  So Cat[\s\S\n]*?(?=Dog) or \n{0}Cat[\s\S]*?(?=Dog) work to do that.  There are a few questi9ns here about this.

Great, but how can I make multi-line to default?

Just add \n{0} at the start of all your patterns.
