# How can I replace in Visual Studio Code every one newline in a document, but not every two newlines (or more)?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I downloaded files through FTP and it added newlines after each line. Now, in my code I had blank lines added for context. After downloading, each empty line I added is now three empty lines.

So if I remove all blank lines with a regex expression like this `^\n` it removes also those lines I added for context. And this `^\n{1}` doesn't help either.

This is an example of HTML that I have now after downloading it through FTP:

```
<nav>

  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>

  </ul>

</nav>



<div>new context</div>



<div>new context</div>
```

This is what I would want it to look like:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



<div>new context</div>



<div>new context</div>
```

Basically what I need is a regex expression that would find all empty lines that aren't after or before another empty line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works to find a single blank line

Find: `(\S[^\S\n]*\n)[^\S\n]*\n(?![^\S\n]*\n)`
Replace: `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/7IbV1Y/1

Explained

```
 ( \S [^\S\n]* \n )            # (1) A line with a piece of non-wsp text 
 [^\S\n]* \n                   # Single blank line with a line break
 (?! [^\S\n]* \n )             # Not a blank line with a line break ahead
```

Comment: Ah, now it's working! Didn't think that last update was that important.

Comment: Works on lines that have spaces on them too. If you want it to work only on lines that don't have spaces, then look at my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55382979/10060799

Answer (score 2):

In vscode when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> enable regex and insert the following into the *Find* field:

```
>\n\n(?!\n)
```

and

```
>\n
```

into the *Replace* field. Now select *Replace All*.

This will lead to the result you described in your original question. I tested it with vscode 1.32.3

Comment: It deleted all the closing tags from all the ends of the lines.

Comment: Sure you did not forget the `>\n` in the replace box? For me it works as expected in vscode 1.32.3

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I missed that > closing tag from the replace field.

Answer (score 1):

What you might do is match a single line where there is at least a non whitespace char present. Then match the following empty line followed by a newline. That will also take into account if the empty lines contains spaces themselves.

Then use a positive lookahead to assert that on the next line there is a non whitespace character present.

Replace those matches with the first capturing group `$1`

```
^([ \t]*\S.*\n)[ \t]*$\n(?=[ \t]*\S)
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group

  - `[ \t]*\S.*\n` Match 0+ times a space or tab, then a non whitespace char followed by matching until the end of the string and a newline
- `)` Close group
- `[ \t]*$\n` Match an empty line or only spaces or tabs
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what follows

  - `[ \t]*\S)` Match 0+ times a space or tab followed by a non whitespace char
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zwqvec/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
(?<!\n)\n(?!\n$)
```

with `g` and `m` options and replace with an empty string.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/uEpQ0L/1

Comment: how do I use ```g``` and ```m``` options in VS Code?

Comment: Search the Weg. E.g.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options

Comment: I don't know the exact setup for VS Code but `g` means global and `m` means multiline.  Here's a resource for multiline, at least: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150941/multi-line-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: The negative look behind feature is not supported in all browsers. I don't think it's supported in VS Code, since it is returning an error.

Comment: @saritonin After research I think it is the default when using ```\n``` in a regex. As seen here for multi line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52647894/multiline-regular-expression-search-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Check https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_29#_multiline-search I found there description concerning multiline and lookbehind / lookahead.

Comment: Upon looking further I have found that the lookbehind assertion was updated in the last version 1.32. It was missing from the release notes as seen here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68004

Comment: After updating to the latest version I am not getting an invalid error when inserting the above regex in the search field. Only it isn't giving me the desired result. After a little playing around this works for me: `(?<!^\n)^\n(?!\n$)`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

After seeing [Valdi_Bo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7388477/valdi-bo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55382953/10060799) it seemed like a very good solution. The only problem is, it doesn't work properly in VS Code. So in order for it to work in VS Code, you must be updated to version 1.32 and change the regex to:

```
(?<!^\n)^\n(?!\n$)
```

and then I got the desired result as seen here:
https://regex101.com/r/b3Jnk2/1

**Previous Answer:**

This regex did it for me.

`^(\n)(?!\n{2})`
This is the result I got:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">London</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tokyo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div>new context</div>

<div>new context</div>
```

After you do this and you still have a couple of empty lines that you want to get rid of but not those empty lines that where added for context, use this regex:
`^(\n{2})`

Comment: Can be pretty helpful when downloaded files from ftp get corrupted in such away. Best thing to do is make sure it doesn't happen next time, see - https://superuser.com/questions/1091022/stop-filezilla-from-inserting-blank-lines-in-text-files