# Finding all XML Files containing specific strings using REGEX

Tags: regex, xml, visual-studio-code

I use VSCode for salesforce and I have hundreds of fieldsets in the sandbox, I would like to use REGEX to find all XML files that contains these 2 words in any order:

```
LLC_BI__Stage__c 
LLC_BI__Status__c
```

I have tried using these REGEX but it did not work, I am assuming because the strings are in different lines:

```
(?=LLC_BI__Stage__c)(?=LLC_BI__Status__c)

^(?=.*\bLLC_BI__Stage__c\b)(?=.*\bLLC_BI__Status__c\b).*$

(.* LLC_BI__Stage__c.* LLC_BI__Status__c.* )|(.* LLC_BI__Status__c.* LLC_BI__Stage__c.*)
```

e.g, this XML File contains the 2 strings and should be returned

```
<displayedFields>
    <field>LLC_BI__Amount__c</field>
    <isFieldManaged>false</isFieldManaged>
    <isRequired>false</isRequired>
</displayedFields>
<displayedFields>
    **<field>LLC_BI__Stage__c</field>**
    <isFieldManaged>false</isFieldManaged>
    <isRequired>false</isRequired>
</displayedFields>
<displayedFields>
    <field>LLC_BI__lookupKey__c</field>
    <isFieldManaged>false</isFieldManaged>
    <isRequired>false</isRequired>
</displayedFields>
<displayedFields>
    **<field>LLC_BI__Status__c</field>**
    <isFieldManaged>false</isFieldManaged>
    <isRequired>false</isRequired>
</displayedFields>
```

Comment: On Linux go to folder where all of your files are saved:
`grep -l LLC_BI__Stage__c * | xargs grep -l LLC_BI__Status__c`
should give you the list you want, on windows just use `findstr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to find either one of them and according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150941/multi-line-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio-code) use `[\s\S\r]` to match any character including newlines.

If there is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/74395) using `[\s\S\r]` you migh tuse `[\S\r\n\t\f\v ]*` instead.

```
(?:LLC_BI__Stage__c[\S\s\r]*LLC_BI__Status__c|LLC_BI__Status__c[\S\s\r]*LLC_BI__Stage__c)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `LLC_BI__Stage__c[\S\s\r]*LLC_BI__Status__c` Match first part till second part
  - `|` Or
  - `LLC_BI__Status__c[\S\s\r]*LLC_BI__Stage__c` Match second part till first part
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/zMDWw8/1) and [Regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xrLBNd/1)