# Match the beginning of a file in a VSCode regex search

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to match the beginning of a file in a VSCode regex search to find and remove the following pattern:

```
//
Anything else to leave in place
etc.
```

I'd like to remove the first line in all files that contain `//\n` as the first characters. However when I perform a regex search for `//\n` it matches all occurences in all files obviously, regardless of their position in the file.

The regex language mentions the existence of `\A` to match the beginning of a line, or file in some editors, but VSCode rejects this regex as invalid: `\A//\n`.

So my question is, how can I match the beginning of a file in VSCode to achieve what I need?

Comment: How about a negative lookbehind on `.`? That should only match stuff not preceded by anything at all. <EDIT> seems lookbehind [doesn't actually work on VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42179046/395685).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The beginning of a file in Visual Studio Code regex can be matched with

```cs
^(?<!\n)
^(?<![\w\W])
^(?<![\s\S\r])
```

You may use

**Find What**: `^//\n([\s\S\r]*)`
**Replace With**: `$1`

Or, since nowadays VSCode supports lookbehinds as modern JS ECMAScript 2018+ compatible environments, you may also use

**Find What**: `^(?<![\s\S\r])//\n`
**Replace With**: empty

If you wonder why `[\s\S\r]` is used and not `[\s\S]`, please refer to [Multi-line regular expressions in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150941).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `//` -   a `//` substring
- `\n` - a line break
- `([\s\S\r]*)` -  Group 1 (`$1`): any  0  or more chars as many as possible up to the file end.

The `^(?<![\s\S\r])//\n` regex means:

- `^(?<![\s\S\r])` - match the start of the first line only as `^` matches start of a line and `(?<![\s\S\r])` negative lookbehind fails the match if there is any 1 char immediately to the left of the current location
- `//\n` - `//` and a line break.

Comment: `^(?<![.\n])` is probably incorrect: it will look for places that are not preceded by newlines (good) and actual dots (not good). I use  just `^(?<!\n)`

Comment: @DesmondHume You know, it is working, but you are right that `\n` alone in the lookbehind will do.

Answer (score 0):

Already has a great answer, just one more example.

#### I have ansible files that start with

`---`

#### And i wanted to insert above the file mode

`# code: language=ansible`

#### VSCode search & replace

`^(?<![\s\S\r])---\n`

`# code: language=ansible\n---\n`