# Replace string with carriage return line feed with regular expression in Visual Studio Code

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I would like to replace, in all project files, all instructions log.info NOT equal to:

```
log.info(
                `DEBUG other strings...
);
```

with nothing (I want to delete them in all files); for example, this log.info should be removed:

```
log.info(
                `remove this instruction!!!
);
```

but not this (it has DEBUG has first word):

```
log.info(
                `DEBUG other strings...
);
```

Pay attention, log.info() could be also on a single line, for example:

```
log.info(`remove this instruction!!!);<br>
log.info(`DEBUG other strings...);<br>
```

I have tried this, with no result:

```
log.(info|warn|error)\([\n|\s]`*(?!DEBUG).*\)
```

Comment: Perhaps like this `log\.info\((?:(?!DEBUG|\);)[\s\S])*\);` https://regex101.com/r/wan9rr/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird In VSCode, [any char is matched](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41151078/3832970) with `[\w\W]` or `[\s\S\r]` or `[^\r]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right! Now it works :-)  `log\.info\((?:(?!DEBUG|\);)[\w\W])*\);` https://regex101.com/r/os9kqm/1

Comment: Well, I'd suggest ``\blog\.(?:info|warn|error)\((?!\s*`DEBUG\b)[\w\W]*?\);``

Comment: @Yellow75 Should `DEBUG` always be the first word after the opening parenthesis?

Comment: @The fourth bird: yes, `DEBUG` is always the first word after opening parenthesis and backtick.

Comment: @Yellow75 Ok, then Wiktors pattern is the way to go

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew: you are right! Thanks Wiktor and everybody.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
\blog\.(?:info|warn|error)\((?!\s*`DEBUG\b)[\w\W]*?\);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8T3dGT/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `log\.` - `log.` string
- `(?:info|warn|error)` - either `info`, `warn` or `error`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?!\s*`DEBUG\b)`- a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is 0+ whitespaces, a backtick,`DEBUG` as whole word
- `[\w\W]*?` - any 0 or more characters, as few as possible
- `\);` - a `);` substring.

Test & settings:

[image]