# How can I start a regex match from the middle and then backtrack?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a very long string (newlines included) of which I'm interested in finding certain "paragraphs". These "paragraphs" are characterized by:

1. Starting with `new entry`
2. Containing `relevant item`
3. Ending just before finding the next `new entry`

Furthermore, these paragraphs don't have a predictable length, but I want to think that if I can find them by hand by just following the above logic like a monkey, then a regex engine might be able to do it.

However, the point that I don't know how to "teach" to the engine through regex is that I first find the line containing `relevant item`, then I backtrack until I find the previous `new entry`, and then I grab everything until the next `new entry`. How can we do this?

Something like `^new entry[\s\S]*relevant item[\s\S]+(?=^new entry)` seems to cause a memory overflow or things like that, and I can see why because it starts the matches on `new entry` which may not have the `relevant item` until thousands of characters after.

I am personally working on Visual Studio Code, so ideally (but not necessarily) the solution would work in its search-and-replace system.

Comment: What programming language are you using? You should be able to do this in two steps. First split the input using `new entry` as the delimiter. Then serach for `relevant item` in each block.

Comment: @Nick it seems like it may. My internet went out seconds before posting this message (on my phone right now), and I don't know how long I'd have to stay awake until it comes back, so I'll check tomorrow morning. + I think what you just typed in your next message, when tested in regex101, yielded catastrophic something something. But I will try again when I can.

Comment: @Barmar not any language in particular, the text is from a custom text based database of which I need to extract these blocks.

Comment: @Nick `.*` should have been `.*?`.

Comment: @mariogarcc Then please provide the name of that tool/platform.

Comment: @InSync I don't understand exactly what you're asking for. The wall of text is in a txt file, and I'm working in VS Code. If I need to use a more complicated script than what VS Code's regex provides, I'll use python also based on VS Code, or maybe something faster if it was somehow needed. I used regex101 for testing during these past couple of hours before posting the question.

Comment: SO is for programming questions. I suggest you do this with a program, then paste into the application.

Comment: @Barmar you are free to provide a solution in whichever language you prefer. I personally use Python, but it wouldn't make sense to limit your solutions to any one language when the problem is inherent to the text and not to the languages - but a programming (Regular Expressions) problem regardless.

Comment: What I meant to say was, you could do this: [`new entry(?:(?!new entry).)*relevant item.*?(?=new entry)`](https://regex101.com/r/BOwUo6/1)

Comment: @Nick's regex needs to be tweaked to work in vscode (which doesn't include newlines in the `.` class unless specifically included).  So try this: `new entry(?:(?!new entry)[\s\S\n])*relevant item[\s\S\n]*?(?=new entry)`

Comment: @Mark ah yes... [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150941/multi-line-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio-code) would suggest you can just use `[\w\W]` which to my eye looks more logical

Comment: @Mark atNick atInSync thanks folks. The duplicate question was indeed right, and the solution Mark gave already works.