# Replace Asterix with Italics tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, replace

In Git IDE/VS Code find/replace, I have multiple instances where a word (literal string) is enclosed in asterisks- ex. `*Ampelisca*`- and would like to replace the asterisks with italics tags `<i>Ampelisca</i>`

Haven't really tried anything, don't know where to start

Comment: if you have simple cases (no `*` use outside your example) you can use a regex search/replace otherwise you need a parser

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all! I actually did some more searching and found this answer, which worked perfectly after I switched out the bold tags for italics: https://superuser.com/questions/1316681/how-to-replace-asterisk-symbols-with-bold-tags-to-denote-important-words-and with this example https://regex101.com/r/928oKB/1

Comment: this won't work if the text between the asterisks is multiline.

Comment: `\*([\na-zA-Z ]+)\*` works if there are line breaks between asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no escaping or double-asterisk wrappers for other markup purposes like there is in markdown, then you can just turn on regex mode for find and replace, put `\*((?:(?!\*)[\s\S\r])*?)?\*` in the search box, and then put `<i>$1</i>` in the replace box, and then do a replace all.

If there is escaping or double-asterisk things, then you need to sprinkle in some more [negative lookarounds](/q/2973436/11107541) to account for that.

Ordinarily with regex, you'd be able to turn on a multiline flag and then use a pattern like `\*([^\*]*?)\*`, but VS Code has some particularities with matching multiline in its find things (see [Multi-line regular expressions in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41150941/11107541)).

Answer (score -1):

If you're using VSCode, just use the "edit all of type" option in the right-click menu.

Comment: I do not believe this answer has much to do with the question. Please revise if you believe otherwise to make it coherent with the question's content.